How to find out KV engine version for VaultTemplate in Spring Cloud Vault?
We need to support KV engines v1 and v2.
How can we find out which version we should use for ops:
val ops = vaultTemplate.opsForKeyValue(path, VaultKeyValueOperationsSupport.KeyValueBackend.???)

There is isVersioned(String path) method inside Spring Vault Core in org.springframework.vault.core.util.KeyValueDelegate but it is not exposed for usage.

Try create a utility method - determineKVBackend
    KeyValueBackend determineKVVersion(String path) {
        if (KeyValueDelegate.isVersioned(path)) {
            return KeyValueBackend.KV_2;
        } else {
            return KeyValueBackend.KV_1;
        }
    }


And before invoking `opsForKeyValue' try to fetch key based on parameter from environment configuration or code logic
    KeyValueBackend dynamicEngine = VaultUtils.determineKVVersion(path);
    VaultKeyValueOperationsSupport.KeyValueBackend ops = vaultTemplate.opsForKeyValue(path, kvBackend);


How can I get access to KeyValueDelegate ?

You can probably already by injection via Constructor get an instance of keyValueBackend or create your own since it only needs a VaultOperations to work. The constructor and method isVersioned are public.
